# What is the xc16 command to obtain disassembly (listing.disasm) file?

Tags: disassembly, microchip, mplab, pic24, xc16

I want to obtain disassembly (`listing.disasm`) file for my project. My current compilation commands produces .elf, .map and .hex files.
How do I (Or what commands) produce a single `listing.disasm`?
Note: I have multiple C files, but I need a single disassembly file.

I know that there is a option in MPLAB X IDE to create listing.disasm while building. But I'm building using batch file.

Compiler: XC16
Processor Family: PIC24F

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MPLABX, go to Project Properties -> Building, check "Execute this line after build", then add this:

```
${MP_CC_DIR}\xc16-objdump -S ${ImageDir}\${PROJECTNAME}.${IMAGE_TYPE}.elf > list.lst
```

Know you should find the list file in your x-folder.

If you work with a batch file, maybe try this:

```
if "%1" == "cof" goto coff_file_format
:elf_file_format
@echo dump for ELF/DWARF
xc16-objdump -omf=elf -S %2\%3.%4.elf > %2\%3.%4.lst
goto end
:coff_file_format
@echo dump for COFF
xc16-objdump -omf=coff -S %2\%3.%4.cof > %2\%3.%4.lst
:end
```

Comment: will this work? as i'm not building from MPLABX GUI. I have a batch file that invoke xc16 compiler utilities.

Comment: I know how to get this file (listing.disasm) when I build using MPLABX IDE GUI. I want to get the same disassembly file through batch file.

Comment: I already tried "xc16-objdump -omf=elf -S %2\%3.%4.elf > %2\%3.%4.lst" command. That generates object and assembly listing, however C source listing is missing. In GUI i used: window -> debugging -> Output -> Disassembly file listing.

Comment: In GUI, window -> debugging -> Output -> Disassembly file listing. will do what i require, however don't know to achieve same thing in commands.

Comment: Maybe ask the guys from microchip.